# The "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension" extension is not enabled

Tags: php, symfony, routes, dependency-injection, twig

I had a class that was extending `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension`.

However, as I am about to upgrade from Symfony 4 to Symfony 5, and as the `RoutingExtension` class is going to be final in Symfony 5, I decided to swap out my existing inheritance relationship for a composition relationship. Now my class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\CommonBundle\Service\Routing;

use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\Node\Node;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class RoutingExtensionDecorator extends AbstractExtension
{
    private array $blacklistedRoutePatterns;

    private bool $enforceMailingParameter = false;

    private ?RoutingExtension $routingExtension = null;

    /** @var string[] */
    public function __construct(
        UrlGeneratorInterface $generator,
        array $blacklistedRoutePatterns
    )
    {
        $this->routingExtension = new RoutingExtension($generator);

        $this->blacklistedRoutePatterns = $blacklistedRoutePatterns;
    }

    public function setEnforceMailingParameterFlag(bool $flag): void
    {
        $this->enforceMailingParameter = $flag;
    }

    public function getPath(string $name, array $parameters = [], $relative = false): string
    {
        return $this->routingExtension->getPath($name, $this->enforceMailingParameter($name, $parameters), $relative);
    }

    public function getUrl(string $name, array $parameters = [], bool $schemeRelative = false): string
    {
        return $this
            ->routingExtension
            ->getUrl($name, $this->enforceMailingParameter($name, $parameters), $schemeRelative);
    }

    private function enforceMailingParameter(string $routeName, array $parameters): array
    {
        if ($this->enforceMailingParameter && !$this->blacklistRouteMatch($routeName)) {
            $parameters['rel'] = 'mailing';
        }

        return $parameters;
    }

    private function blacklistRouteMatch(string $route): bool
    {
        foreach ($this->blacklistedRoutePatterns as $pattern) {
            if (fnmatch($pattern, $route)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /** @return TwigFunction[] */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return $this->routingExtension->getFunctions();
    }

    public function isUrlGenerationSafe(Node $argsNode): array
    {
        return $this->routingExtension->isUrlGenerationSafe();
    }

    /** @return string */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->routingExtension->getName();
    }

    public function getTokenParsers()
    {
        return $this->routingExtension->getTokenParsers();
    }

    public function getNodeVisitors()
    {
        return $this->routingExtension->getNodeVisitors();
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return $this->routingExtension->getFilters();
    }

    public function getTests()
    {
        return $this->routingExtension->getTests();
    }

    public function getOperators()
    {
        return $this->routingExtension->getOperators();
    }
}
```

... and here is the relevant part of my `services.xml` file, which has not changed:

```
    <service id="MyBundle\CommonBundle\Service\Routing\RoutingExtensionDecorator" decorates="twig.extension.routing">
        <argument type="service" id="router"/>
        <argument>%mailing.parameter.enforce.blacklist.patterns%</argument>
    </service>
```

This seems to work well in that my 33 existing integration test assertions all pass. But when I try to load a page in the browser, I find that the line `<a href="{{ path('home_page_home_page_index') }}">` triggers a `Twig\Error\RuntimError` complaining that `The "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension" extension is not enabled.`

So it seems there was previously some magic that was happening in which Symfony was somehow automatically sensing that there was a class inheriting from `RoutingExtension` and using it, and now that magic is no longer happening. (To be clear: The fully qualified class name of my decorator has not changed. It was in use before under the same name, though it was a bit of a misnomer at that time, as it was previously extending the `RoutingExtension` class rather than decorating it.)

Does anyone know how I can jog Symfony's memory on this? I tried injecting `twig.extension.routing` into my decorator's constructor, but I then get a complaint from Symfony about a detection of a circular reference.

Comment: did you try adding <tag name="twig.extension"/> ?